# How to correctly dump IDT entries in amd64?

Tags: c, windows, x86, kernel

The following code:

Header:

```
// InterruptDescriptorTable.h

#define MAX_IDT_ENTRIES 256

#define MAKELONG(a, b)  ((unsigned long) (((unsigned short)(a)) | ((unsigned long) ((unsigned) (b))) << 16 ))

/* SIDT returns IDT in following format */
#pragma pack(1)
typedef struct
{
    unsigned short IDTLimit;
    unsigned short LowIDTBase;
    unsigned short HighIDTBase;

} s_idt_info;
#pragma pack()

/* entry in IDT ( interrupt gate ) */
#pragma pack(1)
typedef struct
{
    unsigned short LowOffset;
    unsigned short selector;
    unsigned char unused_lo;
    unsigned char segment_type:4;
    unsigned char system_segment_flag:1;
    unsigned char DPL:2;                    // Descriptor Privilege Level
    unsigned char P:1;                      // Present
    unsigned short HighOffset;

} s_idt_entry;
#pragma pack()
```

Main:

```
// driver.c
#include <ntddk.h>

#include "InterruptDescriptorTable.h"

const WCHAR deviceNameBuffer[] = L"\\Device\\MyDevice";

PDEVICE_OBJECT g_RootkitDevice; // pointer to device object

NTSTATUS
//STDCALL
_DriverDispatch(IN PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject,
               IN PIRP Irp)
{
    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}

VOID
//STDCALL
_DriverUnload(IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject)
{
    DbgPrint("DriverUnload() !\n");
    return;
}

NTSTATUS
_DriverEntry(IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject,
             IN PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath)
{
    DbgPrint("DriverEntry() !\n");

    s_idt_info idt_info;        // returned by sidt
    s_idt_entry *idt_entries;   // obtained from idt_info
    unsigned int count;
    unsigned long addr;

    // load idt_info
    __asm ("sidt %0" : "=w" (idt_info));

    idt_entries = (s_idt_entry*) (long long)MAKELONG(idt_info.LowIDTBase, idt_info.HighIDTBase);

    for(count = 0; count < MAX_IDT_ENTRIES; ++count)
    {
        s_idt_entry *i = &idt_entries[count];

        addr = MAKELONG(i->LowOffset, i->HighOffset);

        DbgPrint("Interrupt %d, %lu", count, addr);
    }

    DriverObject->DriverUnload = _DriverUnload;

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```

Is compiled to a .sys file using using MinGW-x64 (GCC) in Code::Blocks.

When Inserted into a Windows 7-64bit VM running on VirtualBox, it generates the following BSOD:
[image]

I noticed it only happens when I attempt to print the variable 'addr'. No idea why exactly or how to fix it. Printing 'count' twice is just fine.

The following code is used to load / unload the driver:
http://pastebin.com/0Axy4WkZ

Comment: In 64-bit code, one thing I believe is that [SIDT](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/SIDT.html)  returns back a 10 byte structure (2 byte limit + 8 byte base). In 32-bit it would be 6 bytes (2 byte limit + 4 byte base). If this code is running in 64-bit mode then SIDT will be overwriting part of the stack because you have only allocated 6 bytes of space (via `gdt_info` rather than 10 bytes. In 64-bit code `LowIDTBase` and HighIDTBase` should be 32-bit values (`uint32_t` or `unsigned int`)

Comment: @MichaelPetch I think I solved it thanks to you - .c: http://pastebin.com/tEhhL6cp , .h: http://pastebin.com/hDBjmwcG . One last thing - the original MAKELONG macro generates 0xFFFF1234 out of MAKELONG(0x1234, 0x5678) , and my macro generates 0x0123456789ABCDEF out of MAKELL(0x01234567, 0x89ABCDEF) . thats the correct thing, right?

Comment: @J.Doe - you nothing fix - you definition for IDT entry is invalid for amd64 - correct is  `KIDTENTRY64` in my code

Comment: 1) bug was not in DbgPrint, but in previous line when you try access `s_idt_entry` by invalid address 2) you fix `s_idt_info` (but forget about 6 byte padding before IDTLimit - with this you will be not need use `#pragma pack(1)` - you use unaligned data. 3) now you use valid address for IDT array - as result no crash - but you definition for s_idt_entry remaining old and invalid - as result you use wrong data

Comment: @RbMm Can you send me a link of official definitions? Couldn't get it out of Google

Comment: @J.Doe - for definition of IDT in 64 bit (long mode) you can download intel or amd pdf manuals, or using say this - http://wiki.osdev.org/Interrupt_Descriptor_Table#IDT_in_IA-32e_Mode_.2864-bit_IDT.29 - about how it defined in `cpp` - it "not documented" in WDK headers, but if parsing `ntoskrnl.pdb` we got next structs - https://doxygen.reactos.org/d9/d7c/ndk_2amd64_2ketypes_8h_source.html#l00462

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you use wrong definition for IDT structs in 64 bit mode. correct code for amd64 is next:

```
union KIDTENTRY64
{
    struct
    {
        USHORT OffsetLow;
        USHORT Selector;
        USHORT IstIndex:3;
        USHORT Reserved0:5;
        USHORT Type:5;
        USHORT Dpl:2;
        USHORT Present:1;
        USHORT OffsetMiddle;
        ULONG OffsetHigh;
        ULONG Reserved1;
    };
    UINT64 Alignment;
};

struct KDESCRIPTOR64
{
    USHORT Pad[3];
    USHORT Limit;
    PVOID Base;
};

void DumpIDT()
{
#ifdef _AMD64_

    KDESCRIPTOR64 descr; 
    __sidt(&descr.Limit);

    if (ULONG n = (descr.Limit + 1)/ sizeof(KIDTENTRY64))
    {
        int i = 0;
        KIDTENTRY64* pidte = (KIDTENTRY64*)descr.Base;

        do 
        {
            ULONG_PTR addr = ((ULONG_PTR)pidte->OffsetHigh << 32) + 
                ((ULONG_PTR)pidte->OffsetMiddle << 16) + pidte->OffsetLow;

            DbgPrint("Interrupt %u -> %p\n", i++, addr);

        } while (pidte++, --n);
    }
#endif  
}
```

Comment: Side note: I believe the OP is using MinGW-64/GCC, so things may be a bit different (although general concept the same). `__sidt` isn't an available intrinsic in GCC (although it is in MSVC) for example. Unfortunately the OP didn't really spell this out in the question, and I'm basing it on a previous question they asked today.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thanks for pointing that out, compiler really is MinGW-64/GCC and I edited the question.

Comment: @J.Doe - task not in compiler here, but definitions of `KIDTENTRY64` and `KDESCRIPTOR64`

Comment: @RbMm why do I need 6 bytes padding?

Comment: @J.Doe for correct align data  - to be `Base` on native (in this case 8 byte) align. however I use - `__sidt(&descr.Limit);` but not `__sidt(&descr);` . and not need `#pragma pack` - in ia32/amd64 processor handle unaligned data read/write but this is bad for performance

Comment: @RbMm so I don't actually need to pad it .. ?

Comment: @J.Doe - this is question of performance and effective code - if you not need this - so can not use pad, but #pragma pack

Comment: @RbMm OK, so, at last - does this look like a valid IDT dump? http://imgur.com/a/EEH4d

Comment: @J.Doe - yes, now sure all is ok